# Adding 4 lines in one plot

Tags: r, plot, line

Is it possible to add 4 lines in one plot in r? I am using the following code but the maximum lines I am able to add is only 3, the fourth line does not appear.

```
set.seed(5984)
r <- rnorm(1000, 0.5, 1)
i <- rnorm(1000, 0.45, 1)
r1 <- rnorm(1000, 4, 1)
r2 <- rnorm(1000, 4, 1)

plot(density(r), xlim=c(-5, 5), ylim=c(0, 0.45), col="#CD0000", lwd=2)
lines(density(i), col="#7D26CD", lwd=2)
lines(density(r1), lty=2, col="#FA8072", lwd=2)
lines(density(r2), col="#FF8247", lty=2, lwd=2)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can't reproduce that, I'm getting four "lines". Do `graphics.off()` one time and try again, maybe the `par`s are messed up.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. It worked now, I didn't change anything but for some reason now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add multiple lines to one plot with `lines()`.

For exapmle:

```
r <- rnorm(1000, 0.5, 1)
i <- rnorm(1000, 0.45, 1)
r1 <- rnorm(1000, 4, 1)
r2 <- rnorm(1000, 4, 1)

data <- data.frame(r,i,r1,r2)

plot(0.0, xlim=c(-5, 5), ylim=c(0, 0.45))

cl <- rainbow(ncol(data))

for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
  lines(density(data[,i]),col = cl[i],lwd=2)
}
legend("topleft", legend = 1:ncol(data), col=cl, lwd=2) # optional legend
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for teaching me this.